# Функция рандомного числа с исключением предыдущих результатов

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию выбора рандомного числа, в которой исключались бы результаты предыдущих срабатываний? Создать отдельный массив с результатами и каждый раз сверять с ним? Не будет ли тогда на больших диапазонах сильно замедляться работа функции?

Comment: А в каких пределах это число? Или просто `Math.random()` ? Про массив - да, получается так) Только заранее надо будет проверить, нет ли уже в нем этого числа.

Comment: Да можно было бы сделать проще. Сформировать массив в нужном диапазоне, перемешать, а дальше просто рандомно вырезать элемент из массива.

Comment: Вот решение вашей задачи https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/785883/How-to-generate-non-repeating-numbers-in-Javascrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто оставлю тут пример)

```js
const array = [];

const randomInteger = (min, max) => {
  const rand = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));

  if (~array.indexOf(rand)) return randomInteger(min, max);

  array.push(rand);

  return rand;
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(array);
  console.log(randomInteger(5, 10));
}, 3000)
```